# replace jquery function with var

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

I try to replace a jquery chaned function with a var but it doesnt work (synthax error)

Triing something like this:

```
var foo = 'next()';
$(this).+foo+.show();
```

Is it possible somehow to realize that? foo is a var which changes to 'prev()' in another if condition

Comment: Only with `eval`; don't. Instead, use conditionals.

Comment: No, not only with eval. Also, if you're going to mention conditionals, you should offer ggzone a bit of advice on where to learn about them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var foo = 'next';
$(this)[foo]().show();
```

---

By setting only the method name to the variable, you can use the `[]` notation and use the variable to retrieve the `next` property of the jQuery object.

This is equivalent to...

```
$(this)['next']().show();
```

which is equivalent to...

```
$(this).next().show();
```

Comment: that way you are not invoking foo

Comment: Just to build on this, in JavaScript `foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` mean the same thing, with `foo['bar']` having that advantage that you can use a variable for the key.

Comment: You'll need `[foo]()` to execute the method.

Comment: @zapthedingbat: Thanks, yeah I forgot the `()` at first but added them back in when updating.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
var foo = 'next';
$(this)[foo]().show();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two options that I see:

```
var foo = next; // use the OBJECT here, not a string
$(this).foo().show();

OR

var foo = false;
if (foo)
  $(this).next().show()
else
  $(this).prev().show();
```